# docker network host not available?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

i am trying to run a webserver+ api locally. i am using a docker compose file:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./web/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8910:8910"
     network_mode: host
  api:
    env_file: .env
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./api/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8911:8911"
    network_mode: host
```

when i `docker compose --env-file .env up --build` it builds and runs the images. But i cannot reach localhost:8911 nor localhost:8910 form the host machine.

Do i have a wrong understanding here or is there something wrong with the configuration

Comment: And those images are set to listen on those ports?

Comment: What kind of "unreachable" returns localhost:8910 ? What kind of app are you running ?

Comment: If i remove `network_mode: host`  both containers start and i can access them via localhost:8910 / 8911 from the host machine. BUT both containers have ties to databases and other services runnnig on the local machine. since this is a testing environment, i need them (both docker containers) to be able to access localhost on the host as "localhost" to be as transparent as possible. 
with `network_mode: host` non of the containers is reachable form the host machine (also checked via netstat -tulpen localhost). so - the containers can reach localhost, but localhost cannot reach the containers.

Comment: edit: i am on ubuntu 22.04 and i am currently not running ufw or any other firewall. if this could have been a problem...

Comment: See [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach) for other ways to connect to processes on the host.  This setup shouldn't require host networking.